# DNS: How can I determine which IP a subdomain is associated with?

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, dns-servers

I bought a domain(tohid.ir.tc) from a hosting company. it seems that it is a sub domain of this domain(Ir.tc).

it made lot's of problems for me. I don't now to which DNS server it is pointing. both whois query and domain reseller say that it is pointed to my host. but the hosting company says that is is not pointing to their server. when I enter it it says "The server at tohid.ir.tc is taking too long to respond."

"Ir.tc" domain is pointing http://zoneedit.com/. but I can't tell for sure where http://tohid.ir.tc is pointing.

Comment: iptools.com is useful for tracking down these sorts of problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's try with dig:

```
$ dig -t NS tohid.ir.tc

; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> -t NS tohid.ir.tc
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 45593
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;tohid.ir.tc.           IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ir.tc.          300 IN  SOA ns9.zoneedit.com. soacontact.zoneedit.com. 2012051931 2400 360 1209600 300

;; Query time: 134 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Feb  6 19:57:44 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 92
```

That means tohid.ir.tc does not have NS entry. Only ir.tc is pointed to zoneedit, and this name server point tohid.ir.tc (A) to 94.23.183.101.

If the web server at your hosting company is located at 94.23.183.101 it is ok. If you want something more than an A entry (e.g. you want email address @tohid.ir.tc) you may want to ask the domain provider to add an NS entry for tohid.ir.tc.